# MERN stack app deployment to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mern

Hello I'm trying to set up my aws instance and deploy my mern app (Its not a static app) but I've found so many people doing different stuff and it got me a little bit confused, can anyone explains to me the process that I will have to go through to have a functional deployed mern app with aws? There is no need to go in details I just need someone to explain to me the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up an AWS server with NodeJS:

```
- Create instance.
- ssh into instance
- Git clone the repo
- Sudo apt-get update
- install npm
- npm install
- Add any env or required file that is in gitignore
- sudo ufw allow ssh
- sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
- sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
```

Setup PM2 and configure for port 80

```
- $ sudo npm install pm2 -g
- $ pm2 start index.js
- $ pm2 stop index
- Open up your apps index.js file and change port 5000(default) to port 80
- Also need to upload and configure certificate files to use port 443 with https
- $ sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
- $ sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep `readlink -f \`which node\``
- $ pm2 start index
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just a quick question, do you recomend using windows server or ubuntu instance?

Comment: That is totally based on personal choice but I always use ubuntu ... No experience with windows so can't ans that